# When should I not use IIS 8.5's automatic cert rebinding feature?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I had asked this on StackOverflow, but the community didn't think it was closely related enough to programming.

In IIS 8.5, there is a feature title "[Certificate Rebind](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/certificate-rebind-in-iis85)" that shows up in IIS as "Enable Automatic Rebind of Renewed Certificate" on the Server Certificates screen. From what I understand on the above link, this is used so that an updated certificate can be installed on the machine and IIS will automatically update to use the new cert.

However, this feature is turned off by default. Is there a reason to not use this feature of IIS?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that this feature only works if you renew an existing certificate. I have used X509 Certificates for web sites since 1996 and I don't think I ever renewed one. I always get a new one instead.

So unless you actually renew manually or automatically, this feature doesn't do anything and therefor should be turned off.